# Dynamic variable in terraform provider block

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have this snippet:

```
provider "aws" {
   region = "eu-west-1"
   
   assume_role {
       role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::123456789011:role/MyRole"
   }

}
```

I am wondering if there is some way to get this role arn dynamically, from a cloudformation stack that creates it. Just to clarify, something like this (I know that this won't work)

```
    data "aws_iam_role" "myrole" {
      name = "MyRole"
    }

    provider "aws" {
   region = "eu-west-1"
   
   assume_role {
       role_arn = data.aws_iam_role.myrole.arn
   }

}
```

I am able to get this with a data block, but not inside the provider, since it is causing a loop (and it makes sense), but the provider must do the assume_role of that role before doing anything.

There is a way to trigger the assume role just after the provider is instantiated?

p.s for some architectural reasons, I can't modify the way in which terraform is triggered, so passing the role arn from the command line as argument is not a feasible way.

Thank you!

Comment: For that to work, you would already need to have working provider to access aws. How would you access aws before a provider is created?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am meaning. I know I can't do that in this way.
The real question is: how can i tigger the aws -> assume_role for my provider, suddenly after that the provider is instatiated? (the credentials of the aws account are taken automatically by the pipeline who triggers terraform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a *data source* from the AWS Provider, you already have to have the IAM role to access that account. So that path is not feasible.

What about having those ARN in a file or variable, you could source them. If you have different AWS accounts per environment, and you want to keep the infrastructure still DRY. You can use [Terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was thinking of the same, but I was looking for a confirm :D

Answer (score 0):

Any API request to AWS will need some sort of credentials, so it isn't possible to *completely* eliminate assumptions about credentials.

However, there is a possible compromise here: you can give all of the users/roles who have access to assume this role an additional limited policy that *only* allows looking up roles. I think that'd be an IAM policy whose action is specifically `iam:GetRole`. Then you could use an alternative (aliased) provider configuration just for that lookup, using the result to then populate the default provider configuration:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias = "role_lookup"

  region = "us-west-1"
}

data "aws_iam_role" "assume" {
  provider = aws.role_lookup

  name = "MyRole"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-1"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = data.aws_iam_role.assume.arn
  }
}
```

This is not a typical Terraform pattern -- it's not very common for one provider configuration to depend on another instance of itself -- but it should work as a logical extension of how Terraform deals with dependencies between providers.

It's also worth noting that role ARNs are derived entirely systematically from the role name and the account id, so if you're willing to hard-code that assumption (which seems unlikely to change) then there's another variant of the above that doesn't require the main credentials to have special access to look up IAM roles:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias = "identity"

  region = "us-west-1"
}

data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {
  provider = aws.identity
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-1"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/MyRole"
  }
}
```

This one works by fetching the account id associated with the main credentials, and then interpolating that account id into the ARN while hard-coding the role name.

In both of these cases I'm assuming that the role you're assuming belongs to the same account as the principle which is assuming it. A cross-account assume role would not work this way because there would be no way to automatically infer the target account id, and so that would always need to be provided separately, such as via an input variable.